# For loop works faulty in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have a simple for loop inside jQuery but it is **not** working fine in Firefox.

Problem: It writes my variable fine but if you look at the Firefox tab it says

> Connecting...

all the time.

Also if I check my script with Firebug it says:

> No Javascript on this page

although it writes my variable.

What I am doing wrong here? [**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/f2jFc/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var i=0;
      for(i=0;i<=3;i++) {
          document.write(i);
      }
      //alert("working");
});
```

Comment: come on, jsFiddle isn't that hard to use. The fields are labeled _HTML_, _CSS_, _JavaScript_, at least paste the code where it belongs

Comment: If i do that the script will work fine. That is reason why i didn't paste like that.

Comment: The linked script works fine on jsfiddle.net for me in Firefox 15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never use write() after the document has finished loading, it will overwrite the **complete** document(including scripts)

But however, when the issue is the fact that the (new)document didn't finish the loading-process in your example, call [`document.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.close) after `document.write()`

http://jsfiddle.net/f2jFc/3/